# Mysql-specific query in SubSonic

Tags: subsonic

I'd like to add a query to my SubSonic DAL that uses the MySQL fulltext search construct "WHERE MATCH (columnlist) AGAINST (searchterm)", but can't find an equivalent in SubSonic.

Is there a way of using Subsonic to execute a "literal" query - i.e. it just queries with the exact MySQl code I feed it?

Alternatively, could I implement a subclass of SubSonic.Where to run the fulltext search? If so, how would I go about this?

I'm using SubSonic 2.x. Any ideas welcome. Thanks.

ddoctor

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CodingHorror](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/CodingHorror) to run any SQL you like.